# Laurent series about different regions.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, laurent-series

I am asked to find the Laurent series for

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)}$$

about (a) $\{z: \vert z \vert <1\}$, (b) $\{z: 1< \vert z \vert < 2\}$, and (c) $\{z: \vert z \vert>2\}$.

**Attempt:**

So by partial fraction decomposition, I find

$$\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)}=-\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{z-2}.$$

So for (a), I have

\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{z-2}&=\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\bigg(\frac{z}{2}\bigg)^n
\end{align}

But this only guarantees us $\vert z \vert<2$, not $1$.

For (b), I have

\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{z-2}&=-\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}}\\
&=-\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{1}{z}\bigg)^n-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{z}{2}\bigg)^n\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{1}{z}\bigg)^{n+1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}}\\
&=-\sum_{n=-1}^\infty \bigg(\frac{1}{z}\bigg)^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}}
\end{align}

am I on the right path so far? Thanks for any hints, tips, or advice in advance!!

Comment: @SineoftheTime sorry but i am new to this stuff, go easy on me, I *mean* that, in the $\frac{z}{2}$ series, we converge if the modulus is less than $2$ not less than $1$... am I incorrect?

Comment: no that's correct, but if $|z|<1$, in particulal you have $|z|<2$

Comment: @SineoftheTime I found an error in my work, when I re-indexed, I went the other way in my exponent in the series. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a), $\{z \in \Bbb{C}: \vert z \vert<1\}$, one has

\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{z-2}&=\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{z}{2}\bigg)^n.
\end{align}

For (b), $\{z \in \Bbb{C}: 1< \vert z \vert<2\}$, one has

\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{z-2}&=-\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}}\\
&=-\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg( \frac{1}{z}\bigg)^n-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg( \frac{z}{2} \bigg)^n\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{1}{z} \bigg)^{n+1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}}\\
&=-\sum_{n=-1}^\infty \bigg( \frac{1}{z}\bigg)^{n+2}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}}.
\end{align}

Lastly, for $\{z \in \Bbb{C}: \vert z \vert>2\}$, one has

\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{z-2}&=-\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}+\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{z}}\\
&=-\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{1}{z} \bigg)^n+\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{2}{z} \bigg)^{n}\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg( \frac{1}{z}\bigg)^{n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{n}}{z^{n+1}}\\
&=-\sum_{n=-1}^\infty \bigg( \frac{1}{z}\bigg)^{n+2}+\sum_{n=-1}^\infty \frac{2^{n+1}}{z^{n+2}}.
\end{align}

And we are done with all 3 Laurent series expansions for $\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)}$.

**Added:** If I did these all correct, someone please upvote this answer :-)

Also, why the downvote?! A downvote without comment is worthless...